# How to manipulate date and time in java JDBC and sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, datetime, jdbc

I am making an app that has a database accessed with JDBC.
I am using mysql but later I am going to host my DB on a platform that impose Oracle.

Let's say I want to make a table `employee` that maps the employee, the date he was employed and the time he ends his shift.

What I decided to do is use Date and Time as strings. So to create a table I would use :

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
   ID VARCHAR(255),
   dateEmployed VARCHAR(255),
   endShift VARCHAR(255),
   Primary key (ID)
);
```

Then in java with jdbc I just use the `executeQuery` to search for all the employee and filter the result in pure java.
This method seems naive, as I cannot compare the strings for date and time in sql through a Java jdbc. How can I do this the correct way ?

Comment: if you chose to use 'string' as data type for date and time values in table,  try to use convert function on these string columns to transform to date and time values and do the rest of filtering accordingly.

Comment: @RajaniB The [`CONVERT` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CONVERT.html) changes from one character set to another character set. I don't think that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I decided to do is use Date and Time as strings.

**DON'T**

If you want to store a date and time then use a `DATE` data type (which, in Oracle, stores both a date and a time).

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee
(
   ID           VARCHAR(255),
   dateEmployed DATE,
   endShift     DATE, -- or maybe INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND if you want time
                      -- without a date.
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

> Then in java with jdbc I just use the executeQuery to search for all the employee and filter the result in pure java. This method seems naive, as I cannot compare the strings for date and time in sql through a Java jdbc. How can I do this the correct way?

If you want to filter on dates and, for example, get all the employees who started in January 2022 then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  dateEmployed >= DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    dateEmployed <  DATE '2022-02-01'
```

If you want to use bind parameters from JDBC then your query should be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  dateEmployed >= ?
AND    dateEmployed <  ?
```

and then you set either date (if you do not have a time component to your bind value) or timestamp (if you do have a time component) bind parameters on your prepared statement.